# XNA game frozen

Tags: xna, monogame

I was following a tutorial for creating a 2d space shooter. It was working fine until I added code to spawn enemy mobs, now it just runs but it's frozen. I can't understand why it wont work. there are no errors anywhere or anything like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the portion of code you were working on when this happened.

Comment: I don't know when it started doing it, I ran it after i thought I had completely finished it. There are no errors in the code that visual studio can see.

Comment: Yes but we can't see any of your code, so we have absolutely no idea what the problem is.

Comment: how should I do this? pastebin or? there are multiple classes so its going to be awkward to show you everything.

Comment: Yeah, pastebin sounds good then. Start by posting the Game class. We should carry this discussion on in some chat window

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Usns3LYe, there is the game1 class.

what do you mean by a chat window like IM?

Comment: I think your closing curly brace on line 136 needs to come up to line 101.

Comment: now im getting: 
Error CS0103 The name 'M' does not exist in the current context Roid shoooota Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Roid shoooota\Roid shoooota\Game1.cs 130 Active

Comment: Also shift line 130 to line 101

Comment: Both "M" and "R" do not exist in the current context now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a minor typo with the brackets in your update method.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();
    //updating mobs and checking for collisions
    foreach (Mobs M in mobsList)
    {
        // Updating the mobs, collision checking, etc here
        ...

        ...
        Player.update(gameTime);
        bG.update(gameTime);
        loadAsteroids();
        loadMobs();

        foreach (Roids R in asteroidList)
        {
            // Updating the asteroids, collision checking, etc
            ...

            ...
            M.update(gameTime);
            R.update(gameTime);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

There are two main things wrong in this. Firstly, this bit of code:

```
Player.update(gameTime);
bG.update(gameTime);
loadAsteroids();
loadMobs();

foreach (Roids R in asteroidList)
{
    // Updating the asteroids, collision checking, etc
    ...
    M.update(gameTime);
    R.update(gameTime);
}
base.Update(gameTime);
```

Will be run inside the first foreach loop. You are updating the player, the background, every asteroid, and the window once for each mob, every time you call update. This is only meant to happen once per update, not once per mob that is being updated. *This is why your gaming is lagging or freezing*. This is just a misplacement of the bracket on the mob's foreach loop - shift all this stuff outside the foreach loop.

The other thing wrong is this part:

```
foreach (Roids R in asteroidList)
{
    // Updating the asteroids, collision checking, etc
    ...
    M.update(gameTime); /* THIS LINE HERE */
    R.update(gameTime);
}
```

Here, you are updating each Mob member once per asteroid. If you have 15 asteroids on screen, each mob member will be updated 15 times. Shift that line up into the first foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks mate its not frozen anymore however my enemies are not spawning at all.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `loadMobs`, and step through it. Make sure the bobs are being created, and not destroyed, to begin with. Since the game is no longer frozen, you should be able to use breakpoints from here on out to help find out what is wrong. If you still can't figure it out, post it as a new question.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, im quite new at this and bad too.

Comment: Google how to add break points in visual studio. You can make the program pause at a particular point, view the values in your variables, and execute it one line at a time. It really helps when you're trying to figure out why some function doesn't do what you're expecting